# Shorthand for struct assignment in Go

Tags: go

I have these 3 lines which work:

```
mraStr := models.MRA{}
yamlContent := loader.LoadFile("../mraProj/mra.yaml")
mraStr = Parse(yamlContent)
```

My question is if there is a way to write this two lines in one line in golang?

```
mraStr := models.MRA{}
mraStr = Parse(yamlContent)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the implied signatures for `loader.LoadFile` (returns a single value) and `Parse` (returns a `models.MRA`) you can simply use a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
mraStr := Parse(loader.LoadFile("../mraProj/mra.yaml"))
```

If you want to specify the type (eg: because `Parse` returns an interface), you can use the more explicit [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

```
var mraStr models.MRA = Parse(loader.LoadFile("../mraProj/mra.yaml"))
```